# Can we touch book of hadith without wudu

Tags: hadith, wudu, books, sahih-bukhari

I have the book of summarised Sahih Al bukhari my question is can I touch it without wudu

Comment: And why shouldn't it be permissible?

Answer (score 1):

The majority of the jurists hold the view that it is permitted to touch a book of hadith in a state of ritual impurity, even if it contains some verses of the Quran.

It is known that the Prophet Muhammad ﷺ sent letters to kings, and these letters are hadith and even contained verses of the Quran; and they were handled and read by people who did not have wudu, such as the disbelievers, see e.g. in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/56/152-153).

> ذهب الفقهاء إلى جواز مس المحدث كتب الحديث وإن كان فيها آيات من القرآن في الجملة
>
> ...
>
> واستدل الجمهور لجواز مس كتب الحديث بأن النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم كتب إلى قيصر كتابا فيه آية ، ولأنها لا يقع عليها اسم المصحف ولا تثبت لها حرمته
>
> <sup>— [الموسوعة الفقهية](https://shamela.ws/book/11430/24099)</sup>